# Rotating the spectrum of a bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, rotations, spectral-theory

If $T$ is a bounded operator on a Banach space $X$, and $\sigma(T)$ is its spectrum, what would be an operator whose spectrum is $\sigma(T)$ rotated by $\theta$? For example, $-T$ has as spectrum $\sigma(T)$ rotated by $\pi$.

Comment: This should just follow from the spectral mapping theorem.

Comment: How about $e^{i\theta} T$?

Comment: @copper.hat Doh...I think you are right! That is much easier than I thought.